# Docker Container: integrate volume in image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've an running oracle container from which I want to create an image. This will be shipped to the registry (as an initial dev setup). However, there is an volume configured. Is there a way to integrate the volume in the image? *(I know this might is not best practice but would help a lot for the dev team.)*

```
docker inspect foobar
...
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Name": "0a...c2d",
                    "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/...c2d/_data",
                    "Destination": "/ORCL",
                    "Driver": "local",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": ""
                }
            ],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, volumes are external to the containers run - that's their sole purpose. You're correct that it would be a bad practice, so it's not possible at all.

A Docker container is an isolated application; if you want files to be a part of the image - add them in with a `COPY` or `ADD` command in the `Dockerfile` when you build your image.